# Why isn't it allowing me to use the member of the struct?

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to structs and I'm getting this error:

`main.c:20:14: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int length;
    int width;
} rectangle;


int main()
{
    rectangle.length=5;

    printf("%d",rectangle.length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rectangle` is a name of type, not variable. Either remove `typedef` or define a variable of type `rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

`rectangle` is a type, not an instance of a type.

You need to create an instance of the struct, i.e. `rectangle myRectangle;`:

```
rectangle myRectangle;

myRectangle.length = 5;
```

What you have in your code is analogous to `int = 5;` rather than the correct form `int varName = 5;`